# QString в std string

Tags: jni, qt, кодировка

Здравствуйте.

Есть структура, одно из полей которой - QString.

Где-то в коде происходит следующая инициализация

```
struct_name.qstring_field = some_obj->getIntValue();
```

Т.е. кутишная строка инициализируется интом. Дело в том, что не могу понять, как из этого кустрингового поля достать собственно текст в виде std string или const char *. Методы, возвращающие QByteArray с последующим вызовом constData() и toStdString(), возвращают нечитаемые символы. Что в консоль, что в java-интерфейс через JNI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятен из вопроса тип возвращаемого значения у метода getIntValue(). Скорее всего это int. :-)

```
int i = some_obj->getIntValue();
struct_name.qstring_field = QString::number(i);
```

И тогда все выводится:

```
std::cout << struct_name.qstring_field.toStdString() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

[QString::toStdString](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#toStdString)

Comment: не работает. То же самое.

Comment: QString::number()

Не туда глянул, сорри.